# Tenses: future, past, and simple present

Tags: tense, past-tense, future-tense

> Susan **is** at the factory now.  She **came** to the factory by bus, but she **will go** home by car.

Do these sentences use the tenses correctly?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, upgrate. It is a rule here that we do not do general 'proofreading' requests; but since your title confines our attention to the tenses, perhaps the community will let this pass. Also, it is essential that you do your best to use spelling, punctuation and  capitalization correctly. I will make needed corrections for now; in future, you may do this yourself using the 'edit' link below your question.

Comment: Also, I have removed your reference to 'translation'. We don't do translations either; and in any case, we can only tell you whether your sentences are good English.

Answer (score 4):

Your sentences are correct as they stand.  They do not need changing.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the sentence is correct except She `had come` to the factory by bus.

> Susan **is** at the factory now.

Means,  she is working in the factory write now.

> She **had come** to the factory by bus, but she will go home by car.

Means, while coming to the factory , she had come by bus and she is going to leave the factory by car.

Comment: '... *write* now'?

Comment: I disagree with your implied position that simple past *came to the factory* is "incorrect" here. It is *possible* to use past perfect *had come* in this example, but there's no reason whatsoever to suggest this is somehow "better". They're both equally valid alternatives.

Comment: *Had come* is wrong in this context. The past perfect is used only with reference to some past event or state *before which* 'she' came to the factory; but the only named event/state which her coming precedes is her presence at the factory now, in the present.

Comment: I don't think past perfect is necessary, but I do agree it sounds better.